# Steps wizard and parsley not validating

Tags: javascript, jquery, wizard, parsley.js

i have jquery steps function for my form in wizard.js file

```
$("#wizard-validate").steps({
    headerTag: ".wizard-title",
    bodyTag: ".wizard-container",
    transitionEffect: "fade",
    onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
        if (currentIndex > newIndex) {
            return true;
        }
        if (newIndex === 3 && Number($("#age-2").val()) < 18) {
            return false;
        }

        if ((currentIndex === 0)) {
            return $(this).parsley();
        }
    },
    onStepChanged: function (event, currentIndex, priorIndex) {
        if (currentIndex === 2 && Number($("#age-2").val()) >= 18) {
            $("#form-3").steps("next");
        }

        if (currentIndex === 2 && priorIndex === 3) {
            $("#form-3").steps("previous");
        }
    },
    onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
        return $(this).parsley().validate();
    },
    onFinished: function () {
        alert("submitted!");
    }
});
```

and it's not validating form.. just going to the next steps.

my form is:

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-bordered" action="" data-parsley-validate id="wizard-validate">           
    <!-- Wizard Container 1 -->
    <span class="response"></span>
    <div class="wizard-title">Details</div>
    <div class="wizard-container">
        <input type="text" name="title" required value="" class="form-control"> 
        <input type="text" name="location" required class="form-control" value="" >
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="datepicker1" name="startdate"  value="" />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="time-picker" name="starttime"  value="" />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="datepicker2" name="enddate"  value=""  />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="time-picker2" name="endtime"  value="" />
    </div>
    <!--/ Wizard Container 1 -->

    <!-- Wizard Container 2 -->
    <div class="wizard-title">Details 2</div>
    <div class="wizard-container"></div>
    <!--/ Wizard Container 2 -->
</form>
```

and nothing happens.. just going to next step and that's all.. 
already tried full attributes like: `data-parsley-required` or  `data-parsley-required="true"`

my includes of js files in order is:
1. jquery.js
2. parsley.js
3. jquery.steps.js
4. wizard.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

where is wizard function and parsley check
`return $(this).parsley();` need to change into `return $(this).parsley().validate();` and works perfectly!

Comment: Are you validating each step? Your solution didn't work in my case